# Restore activity

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

When I rotate the phone the activity calls again onCreate and reset everything.
Is it possible to keep data and services like the location manager or I have to save and restore it?
By data I mean something like a list of objects.
How can I prevent code from keep running onCreate every time I rotate the phone?

Comment: for data: persist storage or ratain fragment ... for service: connect to it again ... you can prevent onCreate (android:configChanges in manifest) **but this is not a prefered way**

Comment: I am using the location manager to get latitude and longitude and it takes a lot of time to start showing results and if I have to connect every time it will take a lot of time.

Comment: move location service into some Service implementation ... use startService + bindService ... service will "survive" the orientation change(and still getting fixes) ... after binding the service take last known position from your service

Comment: Can you put some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add this to your `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

### Example snippet:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.activity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" <!-- Keep data on rotation -->
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> <!-- Keep keyboard from "pushing" layout -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Note: This is not the "preferred" way but I use it most of my Android applications(Read here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)**